# JQuery - Prevent auto toggle on screen width changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently starting a website using the [Simple Sidebar Boostrap Template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

If I click toggle to hide the sidebar, then change to a smaller window width, the sidebar will automatically toggle and show again. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Here is the JQuery code from the template.

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: There must be another codeline that catches window resize
or maybe its a @media-screen rule.

Comment: In the `simple-sidbar.css` is a `@media(min-width:768px) { }` query... thats "open" the sidebar... You should edit the css file

Comment: I just read the .css file and figured that out too! Sorry guys!